# Achieving same results with join as with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with three tables: `RGN (region)`, `FAC (facility)` and `RGN_FAC`.  In simplest form, facilities can be associated with more than one region.  These associations are stored in the `RGN_FAC` table.

Each region has a column called PrimaryFlag.  I am attempting to create a list of the PrimaryFlag values of each region associated with a given facility.  I was able to do this using the following sub query:

```
SELECT [dbo].[RGN].PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN]
WHERE [dbo].[RGN].ID in

(SELECT [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID
FROM [dbo].[RGN_FAC]
WHERE [dbo].[RGN_FAC].FAC_ID = 'my fac id')
```

I was told that I could do this more efficiently using a join, instead of a sub query.  However, I am not wrapping my head around how can I accomplish this with a join.

Comment: Unless you need to get values from `[dbo].[RGN_FAC]` there is no point in joining the 2 tables together.  The way you're doing it now is the best way in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, SQL Server has a pretty good optimizer.  But, the best approach is normally `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT r.PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN] r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [dbo].[RGN_FAC] f
              WHERE f.FAC_ID = 'my fac id' AND r.id = f.RGN_ID
             );
```

The strict equivalent `JOIN` would be:

```
SELECT r.PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN] r JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT f.RGN_ID
      FROM [dbo].[RGN_FAC] f
      WHERE f.FAC_ID = 'my fac id' 
     ) f
     ON f.RGN_ID = r.id
```

However, the `DISTINCT` can be a performance issue.  If you know the values are never duplicated in the subquery, you can remove it:

```
SELECT r.PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN] r JOIN
     (SELECT f.RGN_ID
      FROM [dbo].[RGN_FAC] f
      WHERE f.FAC_ID = 'my fac id' 
     ) f
     ON f.RGN_ID = r.id;
```

Of course, if you want performance, then typically an index will help.  For the first query:  `RGN_FAC(RGN_ID, FAC_ID)` is the optimal index.  For the versions using `JOIN` or `IN`, then you want `RGN_FAC(FAC_ID, RGN_ID)`.

Comment: why is the best approach normally `EXISTS` as opposed to `IN`?

Comment: @JamieD77 . . . `in` generally requires evaluating the entire subquery.  `EXISTS` can stop at the first match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [dbo].[RGN].PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN]
JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID
 FROM [dbo].[RGN_FAC]
 WHERE [dbo].[RGN_FAC].FAC_ID = 'my fac id')
ON [dbo].[RGN].ID = [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID
```

The `DISTINCT` can perhaps be removed, depending on if duplicates may occur or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make use of an `INNER JOIN`. This will ensure that you will only get `[dbo].[RGN].PRIMARY_FLAG` where there is a matching `[dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID` for the record.

```
SELECT [dbo].[RGN].PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[RGN_FAC] on [dbo].[RGN_FAC].FAC_ID = 'my fac id' AND [dbo].[RGN].ID = [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID
```

Depending on how your database is setup you may want to consider adding `DISTINCT` to your `SELECT` to avoid duplicate returns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [dbo].[RGN].PRIMARY_FLAG
FROM [dbo].[RGN]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[RGN_FAC] on [dbo].[RGN_FAC].FAC_ID = 'my fac id' AND [dbo].[RGN].ID = [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID
```

Comment: Will return duplicated rows if same [dbo].[RGN_FAC].RGN_ID exists several times.